# Why does pressure reduces in fluid when velocity increases?

Tags: forces

I read in my textbook, where this was explained by Bernoulli theorem
That if height of two points is almost equal and velocity of one increased then it's  pressure must decrease **because their sum is constant.** But what exactly apart from this theorem explains why pressure decreases in the fluid

Answer (score 1):

> But what exact part from this theorem explains why pressure decreases
> in the fluid

The basic principle is conservation of energy. For steady flow, the increase in the speed of the fluid (its kinetic energy) equals the decrease in its static pressure (its potential energy).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure in this context is a form of potential energy. High pressure means a lot of potential energy and low pressure means less potential energy. Let's make a comparison to gravitational potential energy. In the following diagram gravitational energy is converted to velocity (and back)

[image]

In this case your question is now similar to "why does the height decrease when the velocity increases?" I will let you answer this yourself.

Note that for Bernoulli's principle to apply you have to assume the system has reached steady state.

Image credit: https://www.sciencebuddies.org/teacher-resources/lesson-plans/roller-coaster-kinetic-potential-energy